# Android text to speech mapped to Google Cloud Text to Speech Voice

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

We have been reviewing the Google Cloud Text to Speech voices (en-us) to find a one which would be a good therapist. No we see that Android has some build in text to speech voices too.

Does anyone know which Android voice is which Google Cloud voice?

**Google Cloud Voices**

- en-US-Wavenet-A
- en-US-Wavenet-B
- en-US-Wavenet-C
- en-US-Wavenet-D
- en-US-Wavenet-E
- en-US-Wavenet-F
- en-US-Wavenet-G
- en-US-Wavenet-H
- en-US-Wavenet-I
- en-US-Wavenet-J

**Android Text to Speech voices**

- en-us-x-iom-network
- en-us-x-iol-network
- en-us-x-tpf-network
- en-us-x-tpc-network
- en-us-x-tpd-network
- en-us-x-iog-network